# Building a war from multi maven projects?

Tags: maven, web, plugins, ejb

I have three projects which got converted from Ant to Maven build.
I need help with building a war from three projects.

ex)
    proj1 -> proj1.jar
    proj2 -> proj2.jar  (dependent on proj1.jar)
    proj3 -> proj3.war  (dependent on proj1.jar and proj2.jar)

When I build a war and open up this war, I see both proj1.jar and proj2.jar are in the lib folder.

Q1. Do I need to explicitly, copy both jar files to my proj3' resources folder using maven-dependency-plugin?

Q2. I also need to copy some property files from each of proj1.jar and proj2.jar 's resources folder?
Do I use maven-dependency-plugin to copy those property files or do I use maven-resources-plugin?

Q3. Before  I Convert these projects to Maven from Ant? I had ejbModule (ejb project) folder  in my eclipse? In Maven, do I keep this or not? What's the ejb web project's folder structure in Maven?

Thanks much.

Comment: If you already have a war which contains the jar file why would you like to copy them ? The job has been already done by maven-war-plugin. If you need the resources in war put them into the war project instead and not into the jar projects. An EJB can also been created with maven-ejb-plugin. The structure is the same a jar project...

Comment: I asked Q1 because I saw some of online examples showed they explicitly copied using dependency plugin. Is having <dependency> enough in the project pom? On Q3 so, ejbModule folder is not needed(not a conventioin)?

Comment: If you have the jar's as dependencies verything is done by maven-war-plugin. What does "is not needed" mean? Should it be part of your war or not?

Comment: A Maven project can be organized as a multi module project, but from your description it seems that in your case, project 1 and project 2 are first built and installed in the local repository (mvn clean install from the folder of proj1 pom.xml, and from the folder of proj2 pom.xml), and only then proj3 is built (mvn clean package from proj3 pom.xml directory?)  There is a way to do the build all in one step, but  for that you have to organize the proj3, proj2, and proj1 as a multi-module project http://www.codetab.org/apache-maven-tutorial/maven-multi-module-project/

Comment: ..as for Q3, the build process might depend on the application server (for WildFly there should be the wildfly plugin with various goals - I have not used it myself)